# Java ME embedded has no effect on the raspberry pi's gpio

Tags: gpio, java

I recently tried following the instructions listed here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPi_GPIO/RaspberryPi_GPIO.html#section1

I was able to do the extremely simple stuff like output hello to my PI. However, I could not get changes written to the GPIO pins to take effect, using either the method described in the default code, or creating a DeviceConfig.

I used the WiringPi utility to test if maybe my wiring was bad, but I was able to blink the LED from WiringPi. Something interesting, is that using `gpio readall` shown the changes that the imlet wrote to the pin (setting `1` to turn on an LED), but there was not actual change on the LED. This worked the same for trying to turn and LED on and off.

I have the permissions configured correctly (I think...).Is there anyone who has got this working, that could perhaps send me their project?

Comment: It may be something simple like a mismatch between the gpio numbering you think you are using and the gpio numbering being used by Java.  There are at least 3 different gpio numbering schemes.

Comment: @joan I already tried the wiringpi notation, the BCM notation, and physical pin notation. I know that I need to be using the BCM notation, because that is what the example says, and I can observe a change in the correct pin when I call "gpio readall". The problem is that nothing happens in the physical circuit.

Comment: Oh well.  Best to get the obvious possibilities out of the way.  Does the LED light if you carefully move the wire from the gpio to the 3V3 pin?

Comment: @joan yes, moving the wire from GPIO23 to 3v3 lights the led. I can also use the "gpio write" command to write to GPIO23, and the led lights up

Comment: Pity.  That seems to rule out everything but the Java software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update Raspbian to the latest version, then the regular Java 8 SE will be installed. No need anymore to fiddle with Java ME.

With Java 8, and the Pi4J library (http://pi4j.com) it is simple to do GPIO. A very simple example is here:

```
/*
 * Simple LED Flashing
 */

import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinPullResistance;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;

public class Polizeilicht {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("<--Pi4J--> Polizeilicht");

        // GPIO Controller
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

        // PIN 1 is red, Pin 2 blue, both initially off
        final GpioPinDigitalOutput pinRed = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, "Red", PinState.LOW);
        final GpioPinDigitalOutput pinBlue = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, "Blue", PinState.LOW);

        // Button to stop, wired to ground, so we need pull-up
        final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_03, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP);

        do {
            // flicker blue
            pinBlue.high();
            Thread.sleep(50);
            pinBlue.low();
            Thread.sleep(50);
            pinBlue.high();
            Thread.sleep(50);;
            pinBlue.low();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            // flicker red
            pinRed.high();
            Thread.sleep(50);
            pinRed.low();
            Thread.sleep(50);
            pinRed.high();
            Thread.sleep(50);;
            pinRed.low();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } while (myButton.isHigh());
        gpio.shutdown();
    }
}
```

If it's wired up correctly, you will see this: http://youtu.be/kC99wIjlY3I

Comment: Thanks for the code, I ended up deciding to move to normal Java. I did find the error with Java ME, though, the permissions for the VM were not set correctly. The new version 8.1 fixed that.

Comment: You are right. It is easier to make things with PI4J but it is very specific to Raspberry pi. The ones, who would like to learn embedded Java, I would not suggest the use of PI4J.